# How to use POST in python?

Tags: python, json, api

I want to send this curl data using python

```
curl -X POST "http://192.168.12.80:8080/1.0/kb/accounts/a6c08c2c-f3eb-456a-a681-6e5262262e94/payments?paymentMethodId=810d4eae-4668-4c6a-897c-178c041eb67f" -H "accept: application/json" -H "X-Killbill-CreatedBy: demo" -H "authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=" -H "X-Killbill-ApiKey: abcd" -H "X-Killbill-ApiSecret: dcba" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"transactionType\":\"AUTHORIZE\",\"amount\":\"$user\",\"currency\":\"INR\",\"transactionExternalKey\":\"$id\"}"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322430/how-to-send-post-request, Please search before you choose to ask new questions.

Comment: A simple [Google search](https://curl.trillworks.com/) would've sufficed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mimic curl in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024087/mimic-curl-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322430/how-to-send-post-request)

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Install requests package
after installation you should see something like this when you perform 
pip list from command line

```
$ pip list
Package      Version
------------ -------------------
certifi      2019.9.11
chardet      3.0.4
Click        7.0
idna         2.8
itsdangerous 1.1.0
MarkupSafe   1.1.1
pip          19.3.1
**requests     2.22.0**
setuptools   41.6.0.post20191030
urllib3      1.25.7
Werkzeug     0.16.0
wheel        0.33.6
wincertstore 0.2
```

Step 2 : Run the below code to check whether post request works alright,

Please find below an example of python POST request,

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/python/demopage.php'
myobj = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}

x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)

print(x.text)
```

Step3 : Your code using requests shown below,

```
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.12.80:8080/1.0/kb/accounts/a6c08c2c-f3eb-456a-a681-6e5262262e94/payments?paymentMethodId=810d4eae-4668-4c6a-897c-178c041eb67f"'
myobj = {'transactionType': 'AUTHORIZE','amount':'$user','currency':'INR','transactionExternalKey':'$id'}
headers = {'accept': 'application/json','X-Killbill-CreatedBy': 'demo','authorization':'Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=','X-Killbill-ApiKey': 'abcd','X-Killbill-ApiSecret': 'dcba', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
x = requests.post(url, data = myobj, headers=headers)

print(x.text)
```

Comment: where is other headers like api_key and api_secretKey?

Answer (score 0):

The [`requests` package](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/) can help you here. The main call will be `requests.post()` which takes all the parameters you need. For instance

```
import requests
import json

myHeaders = { 'accept': 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'X-Killbill-CreatedBy': demo", 'X-pect': 'The Spanish Inquisition'}

myData = {'transactionType': 'AUTHORIZE', 'amount': user, 'currency': 'INR', 'transactionExternalKey': id }

myParams = {'paymentMethodId': '810d4eae-4668-4c6a-897c-178c041eb67f'}

requests.post(
    'http://192.168.12.80:8080/1.0/kb/accounts/a6c08c2c-f3eb-456a-a681-6e5262262e94',
    params = myParams,
    headers = myHeaders,
    data = json.dumps(myData),
)
```